# null pointer exception in java recursive method when dealing with files?

Tags: java

when i am trying to execute this code i am getting null pointer exception.
i can able to find the problem.that is if any folder contains files as well as directories only first time recursive function is calling after that it is giving null pointer exception.

```
public void generateFileList(File node, String outputFolder) {
if (node.isFile()) {
        //somecode
    }
    if (node.isDirectory()) {
        String[] subNote = node.list();
        for(String filename:subNote){   
        }
        for (String filename : subNote) {
            generateFileList(new File(node, filename), outputFolder);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the NullPointerException on?

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer mostly refer to uninitialized variables, check that your variables have a value before use them in debugger mod.

A solution might be to check that `node.list();` doesn't return `null`.

Comment: its not returing any null value

Comment: it is giving one file and one folder...for the file its recursively calling for the folder(directory)it is giving null pointer exception

Comment: Of course, it's in your recursive call that there is a problem, you have to 'Step Into' with your debugger (F5 if you use Eclipse).